# Async backups vs. Near caches in hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

Lets say I have application with ridiculously high read-to-write ratio.

What one is better:

- number of async backups equal number of nodes in cluster with read-backup-data disabled
- near caches with invalidate-on-change to false

Comment: curious - which route did you end up going with

Comment: For now we went with strong consistency model - no local reads and everything partitioned.

Comment: Alternative kind of cache we're looking into is 'Read Through with Invalidation'. Take a look into LocalRegionCache class - it implements similar concept.

Comment: After having it we will re-run perf tests to identify bottlenecks and will start tuning caches, depends on consistency we need.